# How can I use this dom xss?

Tags: javascript, xss

In this case:

```
var count = $(count_el).data("count");  
$(target).html("hello"+count);
```

Does it mean that only if we can change the `data('count')` in the url can we use this dom xss?
like `<script>codes</script>` etc.

Comment: You can't change `data` with URL. It is set somewhere in JS, try to locate it.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery.data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) stores the information on the element or object itself (if it is an element it first pulls the data from the `data-*` tags).

```js
$el = $("<div data-count='1'></div>")
$el.data('count') // 1
$el.data()        // {"count":1}
```

If, however, you are worried about XSS and somehow malicious HTML is embedded in your data tags, you could use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead of [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

```js
$parent = $("<div></div>");
$child  = $("<div data-count='<script>alert(\"malicious code\");</script>'></div>");
count   = $child.data('count')
$parent.html(count) // this will run the embedded script
$parent.text(count) // this will not
```

Comment: I know how to prevent, I'm just curious about how to create a simple XSS attack in this case

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for, where have you read or seen that [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) is related to the URL?